Getting error : Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
I have my portfolio website and I am integrating a blog into my portfolio, things were on localhost, but after deployment console showed the following error
Blog.js:85 Error fetching blogs: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
enter image description here a screenshot of console error
following is the code to fetch the blog from the backend
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBlogs = async () => {
      try {
        const url = `${host}/blog/blogs`;
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "authtoken": localStorage.getItem("token")
          },
        });
        const allblogs = await response.json();
        setBlogs(allblogs);
        setLoading(false);
        extractUniqueTags(allblogs);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching blogs:', error.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchBlogs();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

I tried to resolve the error using bodyparser but got no success, help me resolve the error

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your client code is almost certainly receiving a HTML error page from the backend, instead of the JSON it's expecting. Try adding console.log(response) before calling response.json() to see what the response is. Also, it's a good idea to check that response.status is in the 2nn range before attempting to use the response body.

You are expecting a JSON response, which you are not getting. Make sure in the backend to use res.json({ "Your data" }), instead of res.send("Your data")
Make sure to use the Network tab in Inspect (browser), so you have a clearer vision on what data you are working with!

I am already doing this, you may see my following code from backend on fetching blog
router.get('/blogs', async (req, res) => {
try {
const blogPosts = await BlogPost.find();
res.json({blogPosts});
} catch (error) {
res.status(500).send("Some Error occurred");
}
});
still getting the error of syntax and unexpected token

You should also do res.json() when catching the error too. That will fix your problem. You might also want to log the error, because something is wrong in the backend.
